# GradCam on trained model

Tags: conv-neural-network, training-data

I have a trained model "model.h5" (keras , Tensorflow) and I use it by "load_model".
Is it possible to apply GradCam to it without retraining?

I searched on the internet and Documents but didn't find anything related.